# How to get a timestamp in UTC but without the time?

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp

I need to generate a date in UTC format, but without the time part, that is, instead of getting:

`Wed, 19 Jan 2021 19:27:00 GMT`

I need only:

`Wed, 19 Jan 2021`

I know that there is a "long" way to do it by formatting the string myself using methods one instance of `Date()` and concatenating them. But I would like to know if there is a shorter way to do it.

By the way, I can only use Javascript vanilla.

Comment: UTC is not a format, it's a time standard. If what you want is a UTC date, consider `new Date().toLocaleDateString('default',{timeZone:'UTC'})`. Formatting of dates has been [exhaustively covered in other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+how+to+format+a+date), e.g. [*How to format a JavaScript date*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date?r=SearchResults&s=1|1682.8208).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by long but the code for extracting only the part you're looking for is pretty short.

```
'Wed, 19 Jan 2021 19:27:00 GMT'.split(' ').slice(0, -2)
```

Edit: If you really dislike this code I just found out that [Date.toDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString) exists

Answer (score 0):

*By using substring:*

```
let d = new Date();
d.toString().substring(0,15)
```